# Usage of hyphens - If I am one of the many product owners of a product, would I say part-product-owner?

Tags: grammar, hyphenation

Or `part-product owner`?

This is in the context of product management, owning a product, its roadmap, schedules, etc delivered to a set of users.

I know `part-owner` is correct, but where does `product` squeeze in here?

Comment: Are you saying that you are part owner of the *rights* to the product, or that you own an *instance* of the product?

Comment: Co-owner may work for you.

Comment: Why not avoid the mess by just saying **part-owner of a product**?

Comment: I meant product owner as in product management, sorry should have clarified. Edited the question.